# How to undelete dynamic partition?

Tags: ntfs

I've tried to remove mirror from software raid 1 but windows removed the whole array. How to restore it? It was standard windows mirroring on dynamic discs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) ? This software is designed to, among other things, locate missing partitions.